# Django Python annotate ManyToMany Relationship with additional information

Tags: python, django, database

my problem is the following. I have two models in the database, which I link together using a ManyToMany relationship. For the admin page I currently use "admin.TabularInline" to bind different objects to one via the graphic. I still want to specify an order in the connections, preferably numbers which represent an order for processing. A bit more figuratively described I have the model "Survey" and the model "SurveyQuestion". So I connect many SurveyQuestions with the Survey. But I can't specify an order, because I don't have an additional field for it. It is not known before how many questions will be in a survey. Nor is it known which questions will be inserted. Usually they are built during the compilation of the survey and may be used later for another survey. I am grateful for every tip!

Comment: Hi, you can actually do a custom prefetch of the ManyToMany objects. Also, you can perform the ordering on the created time field of the Survey Question. Since you will have that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by defining a custom relationship table between the Survey and SurveyQuestion using **through** argument. For example you can define a relationship model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Survey(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Questions, through='Questionnaire')


class Questionnaire(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_order = models.IntegerField()
```

The details and example can be found here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships. If you do not want to mess up with the models, then you have to find out some hack like was proposed by **Ronak Muhta**.